# C# OData Create (POST) Request with nested items

Tags: c#, post, odata

hoping I can have someone help me out with a problem I'm having. We're using a new product which interacts with our ERP system and exposes business objects through REST services using OData. They have some samples and everything which I've gone through but I'm stuck on a key process we're trying to use the product for, which is the creation of a sales document with many items in one request.

I've got the backend working on the server side accepting the request as I can create a POST request manually with a REST client in Firefox and the ERP system accepts the request and creates the document no problem.

The problem is, I'm trying to programatically create the request with just a simple C# console application, but I can't get the request to be created correctly.

Here is what the $metadata of the OData service looks like:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:gp="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData/GenericPlayer" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" Version="1.0">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
    <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="SALES_ORDER">
      <EntityType Name="SalesOrderHeader" sap:content-version="1">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="OrderId"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="OrderId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Sales Document" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="DocumentType" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:label="Sales Doc. Type" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="DocumentDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Precision="10" sap:label="Document Date" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="CustomerId" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Sold-to party" sap:filterable="true"/>
        <Property Name="SalesOrg" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:label="Sales Org." sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="DistChannel" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="2" sap:label="Distr. Channel" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Division" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="2" sap:label="Division" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="OrderValue" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="21" Scale="2" sap:label="Net value" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Currency" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5" sap:label="Doc. Currency" sap:filterable="false" sap:semantics="currency-code"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="SalesOrderItems" Relationship="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItems" FromRole="FromRole_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItem" ToRole="ToRole_SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader"/>
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="SalesOrderItem" sap:content-version="1">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="OrderId"/>
          <PropertyRef Name="Item"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="OrderId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Sales Document" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Item" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="6" sap:label="Item" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Material" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="18" sap:label="Material" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Description" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Plant" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:label="Plant" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Quantity" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="19" Scale="3" sap:label="Order quantity" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <Property Name="UOM" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3" sap:label="Sales unit" sap:filterable="false" sap:semantics="unit-of-measure"/>
        <Property Name="Value" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="21" Scale="2" sap:label="Net value" sap:filterable="false"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="SalesOrderHeader" Relationship="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader" FromRole="FromRole_SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader" ToRole="ToRole_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItem"/>
      </EntityType>
      <Association Name="SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItems" sap:content-version="1">
        <End Type="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItem"/>
        <End Type="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderItem" Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader"/>
      </Association>
      <Association Name="SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader" sap:content-version="1">
        <End Type="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderItem" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader"/>
        <End Type="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader" Multiplicity="1" Role="ToRole_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItem"/>
      </Association>
      <EntityContainer Name="SALES_ORDER" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="SalesOrderHeaders" EntityType="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader" sap:content-version="1"/>
        <EntitySet Name="SalesOrderItems" EntityType="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderItem" sap:content-version="1"/>
        <AssociationSet Name="AssocSet_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItems" Association="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItems" sap:content-version="1">
          <End EntitySet="SalesOrderHeaders" Role="FromRole_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItem"/>
          <End EntitySet="SalesOrderItems" Role="ToRole_SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader"/>
        </AssociationSet>
        <AssociationSet Name="AssocSet_SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader" Association="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader" sap:content-version="1">
          <End EntitySet="SalesOrderItems" Role="FromRole_SalesOrderItem_SalesOrderHeader"/>
          <End EntitySet="SalesOrderHeaders" Role="ToRole_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItem"/>
        </AssociationSet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Now, if I create a request manually (following the instructions from the vendor of the software), the server accepts the request and creates the document in the ERP system. This is what that request looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<atom:entry
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <atom:content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:DocumentType>ZCSH</d:DocumentType>
      <d:CustomerId>0001008657</d:CustomerId>
      <d:SalesOrg>1100</d:SalesOrg>
      <d:DistChannel>10</d:DistChannel>
      <d:Division>40</d:Division>
    </m:properties>
  </atom:content>
  <atom:link
  href="SalesOrderHeaders(0000004970)/SalesOrderItems"
  rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/SalesOrderItems"
  type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
  title="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderItems">
    <m:inline>
      <atom:feed>
        <atom:entry>
          <atom:content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
              <d:Item>000010</d:Item>
              <d:Material>70000559</d:Material>
              <d:Plant>570B</d:Plant>
              <d:Quantity m:Type="Edm.Decimal">1.000</d:Quantity>
            </m:properties>
          </atom:content>
        </atom:entry>
        <atom:entry>
          <atom:content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
              <d:Item>000020</d:Item>
              <d:Material>70000559</d:Material>
              <d:Plant>570B</d:Plant>
              <d:Quantity m:Type="Edm.Decimal">5</d:Quantity>
            </m:properties>
          </atom:content>
        </atom:entry>
      </atom:feed>
    </m:inline>
  </atom:link>
</atom:entry>
```

However, using the following code in C#, I cannot get the Items to become part of the request. They just don't show up. Here is the C#:

```
ServiceReference4.SALES_ORDER ser = new ServiceReference4.SALES_ORDER(uri);
        NetworkCredential c = nc;

        ser.WritingEntity += new EventHandler<System.Data.Services.Client.ReadingWritingEntityEventArgs>(ser_WritingEntity);
        ser.SendingRequest += new EventHandler<System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequestEventArgs>(ser_SendingRequest);
        ser.Credentials = c;

        ServiceReference4.SalesOrderHeader soHeader = new ServiceReference4.SalesOrderHeader();
        ServiceReference4.SalesOrderItem soItem = new ServiceReference4.SalesOrderItem();

        soHeader = ServiceReference4.SalesOrderHeader.CreateSalesOrderHeader("");
        soHeader.DocumentType = "ZCSH";
        soHeader.DistChannel = "10";
        soHeader.Division = "40";
        soHeader.SalesOrg = "1100";            

        soItem = ServiceReference4.SalesOrderItem.CreateSalesOrderItem("", "10".PadLeft(6, '0'));
        soItem.Material = "70000559".PadLeft(18, '0');
        soItem.Plant = "570B";
        soItem.Quantity = 1;

        soItem.SalesOrderHeader = soHeader;
        soHeader.SalesOrderItems.Add(soItem);

        ser.AddToSalesOrderHeaders(soHeader);

        try
        {                
            System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceResponse resp = ser.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException);
        }
```

But this is the request that is generated:

```
<entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SALES_ORDER.SalesOrderHeader" />
  <title />
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <updated>2011-10-31T20:27:42.5387007Z</updated>
  <id>http://.../sap/opu/sdata/sap/SALES_ORDER/SalesOrderHeaders('')</id>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:Currency m:null="true" />
      <d:CustomerId m:null="true" />
      <d:DistChannel>10</d:DistChannel>
      <d:Division>40</d:Division>
      <d:DocumentDate m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" />
      <d:DocumentType>ZCSH</d:DocumentType>
      <d:OrderId m:null="false" />
      <d:OrderValue m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
      <d:SalesOrg>1100</d:SalesOrg>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

I hope this makes sense...any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Also I've found on the odata site this:

http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations#CreatingnewEntries

if you scroll down to the paragraph starting with "When a client needs to create multiple related Entries it can do so as independent operations or -if the Links between Entries allow it structurally- they can perform a single POST with a tree of Entries"

This is exactly what I want, and the POST request shown is just what I need to accomplish, I just can't figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to the guys over on the MS forum, this type of deep insert request isn't supported by the WCF DS client as of right now.

Mega bummer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell the data service context (ser) that there is a link between these objects. Take a look at the [AddLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addlink.aspx) and [SetLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.setlink.aspx) methods. The examples on those pages are very close to what you trying to do.

Bottom line, I think you need to add:

```
ser.AddLink(soHeader, "SalesOrderItems", soItem);
ser.SetLink(soItem, "SalesOrderHeader", soHeader);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: triangle, thanks for the reply. I've beat my head against the wall with this. I tried what you suggested as well, but the results are the same, the request still ends up looking the same.

Comment: I just noticed that you're not adding the SalesOrderItem to the data service context. Can you try adding ser.AddToSalesOrderItems(soItems); and see if that helps?

Comment: Just tried, same result...here is what I have now: `ser.AddToSalesOrderHeaders(soHeader);  ser.AddToSalesOrderItems(soItem);  ser.AddLink(soHeader, "SalesOrderItems", soItem);`

Comment: Are you doing the SetLink as well? I just looked at the docs again and saw that there's the AddRelatedObject method that does what AddObject, AddLink, and SetLink should do in one call. Check it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addrelatedobject.aspx

Comment: lol i was just about to post, i just tried AddRelatedObject as well, same results...this is maddening!

Comment: OK, sorry I'm out of ideas then. Post your question over at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/threads. The WCF Data Services guys hang out there.

Comment: thanks, I've got a post over there too, hopefully someone can see what we're missing...cheers